# radio button selection in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of two radio buttons having same `id`

```
<input type="radio" id="rad" name="mode"value="test" />test
<input type="radio" id="rad" name="mode" value="dev"/>dev
```

user have to select any one of the radio button.so while validating if second radio is selected the following validation alerts always.

```
 if ($('#rad').prop('checked') != true ) {
      alert(' Please Choose mode!!')
        return false;
    }
```

I only have to alert if user did not select any one of them.and no need to alert if user selected one radio button.

In my case if user select first `radio` button it alerts anything but choosing second `radio` it alerts `Please Choose mode.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `length` of `checked radio buttons` like,

```
if (!$('input[name="mode"]:checked').length) {
    alert(' Please Choose mode!!')
    return false;
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/2Hywa/)

Answer (score 2):

`ID` of element uniquely identifies the html element! read this if you keen `:)` https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really

Also : http://jsfiddle.net/Pkq3B/

have fun, lemme know how it goes!

you could use class like this:

```
 if (!$('.rad').is(':checked')) {
      alert(' Please Choose mode!!')
        return false;
    }
```

**html**

```
<input type="radio" class="rad" name="mode"value="test" />test
<input type="radio" class="rad" name="mode" value="dev"/>dev
```

Comment: will not work if the second radio is selected http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RPLyr/1/

Comment: it is not working.plese choose mode alert if i choose first or second radio button

Comment: @Sush like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6YdZ2/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/Pkq3B/ ? sorry bro, lemme know if I understand you right!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for that purpose. You can use pure JavaScript:

```
if((document.getElementById('rad').value!='test')||document.getElementById('rad').value!='dev'))
{
alert("please select");
}
```